# how to get the email address from facebook oauth

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I am using HWIOAuth bundle to integrate login with facebook.
Here is my config section for facebook

```
 facebook:
      type:                facebook
      client_id:           ***************
      client_secret:       ********************************
      scope:         "email, user_birthday"
      infos_url:     "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday"
```

Everything is working fine except email which comes as null.
how to get the email id so I can store at my side.

Comment: Do you tested this with another accounts? Maybe it isn't works for you only, because you have some problems with your email on facebook.

Comment: No, I haven't. Let me check with other users. 
Another question: If I don't get the email Id how to handle that?

Comment: There are rare situations when facebook returns email as null. In most cases it's happens because of internal facebook's problems. Ask your friends to try your login system and check if they has null problem too.

Comment: I tried with some different users too, got the same issue. :(

Comment: I hope that you haven't posted the true `client_id` and `client_secret` :-)

Comment: I got the issue, I had to allow that app for every user from facebook developer account, I am getting email for all the users except the user who created the app in  facebook developer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the paths in `config.yml`.

```
resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
                paths:
                    email:          email
```